# jdeveloper - Package does not exist while compiling on Maven and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, jdeveloper

i'm new to JDeveloper and i am trying to import a Maven project in it.

I successfully did that, although, when i try to build the project, all external packages (that come from Maven dependencies) are non existant from the point of view of JDeveloper.

I checked my maven repo, settings, and the project classpath, and it doesn't seem like the problem is from here. In addition, when i do `mvn compile` on the projet, it compiles normally, and when i import the project to Eclipse, no problem is displayed.

I'd like to use Eclipse (as i prefer it to Jdev), but i'm obliged to use the Oracle IDE.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing the project file (`.jpr`) and correcting the path to the Maven repository.

I used `${maven:maven.local.repo}` instead of the relative path that was used before (`../../../../.m2/repository`).